# Reference Error when pasting new data in a sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am updating multiple worksheets in a workbook with data.  For this, I am using one of the worksheets as a basis to generate new worksheets (using the “Move or Copy” function) and then trimming the number of rows as needed. 
When I paste new data into the new worksheet, I always get an error –
a ref error in the last row, like this:

[image: Spreadsheet with Ref Error]
I have to correct it manually.

I use the formula `=IF(J5="","",K4*3.268)` in cell `L4`, dragged down to populate all the rows, but always get a “#REF!” error. 
The data is about chemical batches – cycle time and yield%. 
The control chart data is centered on cycle time of the batches. 
The batches have been taken chronologically as per Batch start date. 
However, the Batch end date is quite random – in the sense
that it’s not necessary that the earlier batches get done early. 
That is also the reason why I had included `=IF(J5="","",...)` part,
since the Batch end date cell could be blank.

How do I ensure that the error does not occur?

Comment: `#REF` is not correct referential expression. Use `IFERROR()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your screenshot,
you have `L32` set to `=IF(J33="","",K32*3.268)`. 
And then you delete row 33, so cell `J33` no longer exists,
and that’s a reference error.

You have your spreadsheet in reverse chronological order: (in Column `F`)
you have more recent dates at the top and older dates at the bottom. 
It is customary for time-stamped data to depend on the
(chronologically) previous value;
since you have the data in reverse chronological order,
that means that each row depends on the *following* row
(i.e., the next higher row number). 
But when you delete row 33 (and below),
you make row 32 the oldest row in that worksheet,
so there is no older data to look at.

OK, I’m sorry to say that I don’t understand much
of your explanation of the data. 
It might help if you said which column was what
(i.e., shown the column headings)
or said *how* you manually correct the “#REF!” error. 
(I guess it would have been better if I had *asked you*
how you correct the “#REF!” error — I’m sorry I didn’t think to do that.)

Looking at your screenshot,
I realize that, on the sheet without the error, cell `L32` is blank. 
And row 32 is the last row of data — row 33 is blank. 
So I guess that you want cell `Ln` to be blank
on the last row of data.

Or maybe I should just keep my guesswork to a minimum
and state the obvious, simple interpretation:
you want cell `Ln` to be blank
whenever the next row’s cell `Jnn` is blank. 
A simple way to do that is to change the formula in `L4` to

```
=IF(OFFSET(L4, 1, -2)="", "", K4*3.268)
```

`OFFSET(L4, 1, -2)` says “Look at cell `L4`,
then go down one row and left two columns.” 
(If I had used a positive `2`,
it would have meant “… go *right* two columns.”) 
Obviously this gets you to `J5`. 
When you drag it down to row 32, you will get

```
=IF(OFFSET(L32, 1, -2)="", "", K32*3.268)
```

in cell `L32`, and `OFFSET(L32, 1, -2)` will refer to cell `J33`. 
But the beauty (such as it is) of this trick
is that you can then delete row 33 without changing cell `L32`
— so it will continue to refer to the cell one row down and two columns left from itself.

Comment: The data is about chemical batches - cycle time and yield%. The control chart data is centered on cycle time of the batches. The batches have been taken chronologically as per Batch start date. However Batch end date is quite random - in the sense that its not necessary that the earlier batches get done early.  That is also the reason why I had put =IF(J5="","",...) part since the Batch end date cell could be blank.